# simple tooltips created using jquery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery

I have difficult time figuring out, why this code doesn't work. My intention is to display a message when user cliks on tooltip div. After moving mouse cursor out of the div, the tooltip should close.
I need the simplest possble way of displaying a message on a single page. I need to use jquery 1.3.2.Can anybody help? Thank you

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.wrapper').live('click', showBox).live('mouseleave', hideBox);

    function showBox(e){
        var x = e.pageX + 20;
        var y = e.pageY + 20;
        $('.tooltip').fadeIn();
        $('.tooltip').offset({ left: x, top: y });
    }
});

function hideBox(){
    $('.tooltip').fadeOut();
}

</script>
<style>
  .div{ margin:10px;padding:12px;
         border:2px solid #666;
         width:60px;
       }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">sometext</div>
<div class="tooltip">tooltip1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: here is the working code by Juan Mendes http://jsfiddle.net/HUG2Z/3/

Comment: "This code doesn't work" is the worst thing you can say, how about explaining what part is not working, any error messages? You didn't show any HTML elements with class `.somefield`. Best thing you do is create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You sure you really want to use 1.3.2?

Comment: I edited my question to add more detail. Html element is wrapper div. Yes I need to use 1.3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure out why you're using `live` on `mouseleave`.  Without seeing the rest of the code, it doesn't make sense to use it on `click` either. `live` is deprecated in version 1.7 for a reason, so you should not use it, unless you really understand what it's doing and its drawbacks.

The following code works http://jsfiddle.net/HUG2Z/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.somefield').click(showBox).mouseleave(hideBox);

    function showBox(e){
        var x = e.pageX + 20;
        var y = e.pageY + 20;
        $('.tooltip').fadeIn();
        $('.tooltip').offset({ left: x, top: y });
    }

    function hideBox(){
        $('.tooltip').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

If this is now what you want, just change the jsfiddle to better represent your scenario and post it on your question (not as a comment here)

Comment: you so quick I can not even fix mistakes I made in my quesion:)) this code works thank you very much.

Comment: btw. I tried to work in jsfiddle but I did not see an option to choose jquery 1.3.2

Comment: There isn't, you'd have to load it on your own using a script tag. See http://jsfiddle.net/HUG2Z/3/

Comment: Hi, I came across another obstacle. The Html code for .tooltip is on the bottom of the page, while the .somefield is on top. Is there a way to show hidden div near the click area? Thank you

Comment: @user1031742 That is another question, we don't ask two question in one post here at SO to keep the post as useful as possible to other users. Post a new question and link to it here, then both posts will be useful to others in the future

Comment: Thank you, I created new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422893/tooltip-position-near-the-mouse-click