# tooltip position near the mouse click

Tags: jquery

My scenario is described and partially solved here [simple tooltips created using jquery 1.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421563/simple-tooltips-created-using-jquery-1-3-2)
I want to show simple tooltip after click on a html element. However, on my page the html code for tooltip (.tooltip) is on different place of my page (bottom).
Now I need it to show right under the clicked html element.
So far the code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.somefield').click(showBox).mouseleave(hideBox);

function showBox(e){
    var x = e.pageX + 20;
    var y = e.pageY + 20;
    $('.tooltip').fadeIn();
    $('.tooltip').offset({ left: x, top: y });
}

function hideBox(){
    $('.tooltip').fadeOut();
}
});
```

And it works on my page like this http://jsfiddle.net/HUG2Z/15/
How can I achieve to show it right under mouse click in jquery 1.3.2? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the tooltip be absolutely positioned and change the call to `offset()` into a `css()`

Why are you adding 70 to `pageX` and `pageY`? It won't be right by the mouse like that.

http://jsfiddle.net/HUG2Z/22/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.somefield').click(showBox).mouseleave(hideBox);

    function showBox(e){
        $('.tooltip').fadeIn().css(({ left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY }));
    }

    function hideBox(){
        $('.tooltip').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
    margin:10px;
    padding:12px;
    border:2px solid #666;
    width:60px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;

}
```

Comment: Hi, your code works for my situation. I tried Marvin's code as well but it did not work for me. Also what I came across while implementing it on my site - my .tooltip html code was wrapped in a div with position: absolute , which apparently prevented .tooltip to be moved. What I did is to alter position of this wrapper to inherit inside style sheet. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @user1031742 That's interesting, Marvin's jsfiddle seems to work fine, I'm pretty sure his answer is the same as mine, just 2 minutes later.

Comment: He most likely copied the position with **... i just put it in to hightlight it... ofc you'll have to remove.

Comment: Nothing happens on click.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update on your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/HUG2Z/19/

The most important stuff happens here:

```
.tooltip {
    margin:10px;
    padding:12px;
    border:2px solid #666;
    width:60px;
    **position: absolute;**
    display: none;
}
```

and here

```
$('.tooltip').css({ left: x, top: y });
```

Well first of all you will need to position the tooltip absolute so it runs outside the normal box model and can be positioned everywhere. The attributes left and top didnt even kick in because by default most elements have position static. You should probably dive a little deeper into the whole position topic (not that complicated actually) before starting to manipulate it with jQuery.